# Best Practice For Creating Stub Files With Ant

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to create myself a little build script to build a project for me - creating the desired directories, downloading any needed jars via Ivy/Maven and creating some stub files.

The stub files part is what I'm not too sure on what to do.  To take an example, I would want the build script to create a web.xml in a WEB-INF folder.  What would be the best way to do this though?  The only way I know how is to have an echo to a file and then the build script containing my stub code.

Is there a better way than this that I don't know of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're generating or modifying XML content in Ant, I'd recommend [XMLTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/). It can be used to create or modify XML files whilst ensuring well-formedness, entity and encoding issues etc. The problem with plain-text-based tools is that, although they will work in many cases, they have no awareness of the limits the XML standard requires and enforces.

See [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/11/01/xml-manipulation-using-xmltask.html) for an article on how to use XMLTask.

Disclaimer: I'm the author, so I confess a certain bias :-)

Comment: That works a treat thanks Brian as I'm mainly using XML files here.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you're proposing using *echo* to write files like *web.xml*.

It might be better to have your Ant script invoke a templating engine, such as [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/). Texen can be used to [generate arbitrary text](http://velocity.apache.org/texen/devel/).